# Splitting primes and quadratic reciprocity.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading through Marcus's wonderful book Number Fields, and I had two questions on his proof of quadratic reciprocity in chapter $4$.

Marcus states first that if $p$ is an odd prime, and $q$ is any prime, that in the field $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ where $\omega = e^{2\pi i /p}$ that $q$ will split into $r$ primes, where $r = (p-1)/f$ and $f$ is the multiplicative order of $q \mod p$. He says this like it's obvious, so maybe I'm missing something simple, but I do not understand this line.

My second question is that Marcus also claims that the following are equivalent

$1)$ $q$ is a $d^{th}$ power $\mod p$

$2)$ $f|(p-1)/d$

$3)$ $d|r$

$4)$ $F_d \subset F_r$

Where $F_d$ is the unique subfield of $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ guaranteed by the fact that the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]/\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic.

I think $1\implies 2\implies 3 \implies 4$ are pretty trivial, as well as $4\implies 3 \implies 2$, but I can't quite see the equivalence of $1$ with the rest of these statements.

Comment: Recall that if the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is given by $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, then you can see the splitting of the prime $(q)$ by taking the irreducible polynomial for $\alpha$ (which is monic having integer coefficients), reducing it modulo $q$, and factoring the resulting polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_q$. You can do that with $\omega$ and $q$ in the case under consideration. And this also relates to part (4), if I’m not mistaken...

Comment: I see. So this comes down to how the polynomial $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots + 1$ factors mod $q$. I know that it will have a factor of degree $f$ but it's still not immediately obvious to me why $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots + 1$ splits into $(p-1)/f$ factors mod $q$.

Comment: Oh never mind, I see this now, it's because the extension is normal, so all the primes have to be to the same power, and hence the factor of degree $f$ is the same for all the factors. So we have that $f = (p-1)/r$. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Dear @Arturo Magidin , Why the multiplicative order of $q$ module $p$ is equal to inertia degree $f$?

Comment: @Davood KHAJEHPOUR, I think you can find your answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981438/inertia-degree-in-cyclotomic-extensions?rq=1

Comment: @JonHales, Yes, in that link I've received my answer. Thank you so much. +1

Answer (score 1):

Your first question has its answer in the Corollary of Theorem 26. Observe that as $q$ does not divide $p$, so it should split into exactly $\frac{p-1}{f}$ factors, which he has denoted by $r$, and where $f$ is the multiplicative order of $q$ modulo $p$. So, $r = \frac{p-1}{f}$.
In your second question, understanding the equivalence between two statements just as you have already mentioned will suffice to make sure that all are equivalent.